# How to give custom labels for picklist values in salesforce?

Tags: picklist, customlabel

i created custom labels from vf page, But i didn't create some custom labels for pick list values in my vf pages..

How to create custom labels for pick list values in salesforce??

any body help me how to achieve this????

In the below screenshot i created custom label for header only.. i don't know the way how to create custom labels for pick list values in drop-down list..

i'l attached screenshot also..[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you need to translate your picklist values the way you translate any other custom label, this is what you should do.

**Setup -> Translation settings**
Enable translation in your org.

**Setup -> Translate**
Select language, "Picklist value" in setup component and your choice of object.
The result will display all the picklist fields that is present in the selected object.

Expand the picklist of your choice and write the translated value in 'Picklist value Label Translation' column.
Example, if picklist value is 'Earth', then the translated value will be 'Tierra' if the language that is selected in Spanish.

Now if you refresh you VF page, the picklist values will be translated.

*Don't forget to change your language from personal information.